# How to redirect a link and all it's subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess, joomla3.0

I have links that are a joomla blog category that contain articles:

`example.com/old-cat-name/art1`

`example.com/old-cat-name/art2`

that i want to redirect to:

`example.com/new-cat-name`

I don't need to specifically redirect each article from "old-cat-name", I just want ALL of the articles in the old cat name to get redirected to the new category blog:
example.com/new-cat-name

I have admin tools redirect, but this is probably something I need to do in .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample .htaccess I used when I built a new version of my site and wanted to ensure that visitors to the old pages would be permanently re-directed to the new pages and make sure I didn't lose their seo value with Google:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Apply to directories (!-d) and files (!-f)
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

# Static pages
Redirect 301 /enquiries.php mysite.com/enquire

# Listing pages
Redirect 301 /apartments-city-south.php mysite.com/apartments/city/south

# And this for requests which use to contain url parameters, i.e.:
#   mysite.com/view_propery?code=1234
# But are now in the form:
#   mysite.com/accommodation-detail/1234
# Property detail pages
# Detail pages
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^code=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^detail.php$ accommodation-detail-%1\.html? [R=301,L]
```

You must ensure that MOD_REWRITE is on in your Apache config file on your server

Note: Because of restrictions in links in stackoverflow answers I could not include a http:// in the code. Please insert this in front of the lines which start with a domain and suffix i.e. mysite.com, NOT the lines which start with a / JUST the ones which start with mysite.com